# I cant install any program in In ubuntu 14.04 due to zte modem ui PLEASE HELP

Tags: usb-modem, crossplatform, zte

Whenever i try to install anything following error comes

```
(Reading database ... 162729 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing crossplatformui (2.0.6) ...
ztemtvcdromd: no process found
dpkg: error processing package crossplatformui (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
crossplatformui
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Enter /var/lib/dpkg/info

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
```

2.Delete all entry related to crossplatformui

```
sudo rm crossplatformui.*
```

3.Force remove crossplatformui

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq crossplatformui
```

4.Display would be :

```
(Reading database ... 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `crossplatformui' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.

(Reading database ... 159448 files and directories currently installed.)

Removing crossplatformui ...
```

Comment: I dont know how to thank you, this completely solved my problem.

Comment: You don't need to thank me. Helping each other is our job.